# How to make bootstrap collapse responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to show the collapse button and text only on mobile devices and show on desktop the uncollapsed content?

I can use the example and show the text only partly. By clicking on one of the buttons the rest of the text is shown. That is fine for mobile.

```
<p>
Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</p>
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
    </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Button with data-target
    </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
```

But how can I make it to show all of the text on desktop and hide the buttons?
To hide the buttons I can just add:

```
<p class="mobile-show-more">
    Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</p>
```

And add a CSS class:

```
.mobile-show-more {
    display: none;
}
```

I was thinking about using a media query like:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {`

But I am not sure how the class should look.
Of course I could use the '.mobile-show-more' class for the text on desktop, but then I will have the same text twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some things to be hidden on small screens and shown on larger screens, and the opposite, then you could use Bootstrap’s [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/display/). The display properties do break at Bootstrap’s standard breakpoints, but you can change those in SCSS.

Using the example from Bootstrap that you used:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary d-md-none" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Link with href
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary d-md-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-target
        </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse d-md-block" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
            Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Update 1

To answer your follow-up question, to have some content displayed on wider screens, but hidden on small screens and displayed with a button, you have to configure the hidden content in its own row/column setup.

```js
$(".collapse").on("shown.bs.collapse", function (e) {
    var $buttonElement = $($(e.target).data('bs.collapse')._triggerArray);

    $buttonElement.parent().hide("fast");
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-sm my-3">
<h1>One column hides</h1>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2 class="home-headline-15">Lorem ipsum </h2>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="d-sm-none">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                Alles lesen!
            </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse d-sm-block" id="collapseExample1">
            <h3 class="home-headline-15">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</h3>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3 class="home-headline-15">Nam liber tempor cum soluta</h3>
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-sm">
<h1>Two columns hide</h1>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2 class="home-headline-15">Lorem ipsum </h2>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p class="d-sm-none">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                Alles lesen!
            </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse d-sm-block" id="collapseExample2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h3 class="home-headline-15">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</h3>
                    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h3 class="home-headline-15">Nam liber tempor cum soluta</h3>
                    <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Update 2

In response to your second follow-up question, I’ve updated the snippet above to include a listener on the collapse elements for Bootstrap’s `shown.bs.collapse` event. After a collapsed division is shown, a jQuery hide is called on the button that triggered the show event, hiding the button.

I went with a hide animation for the button, rather than having it just disappear, so sighted visitors will have an indication that the button is gone. Visitors that use assistive technology, such as a screen reader, may find the button disappearing a little unsettling.

You may want to leave the button in place as I don’t think most users will care that they now have to scroll past a button to see the expanded content, but in response to your question — yes, it is possible to hide the button.

One caveat for hiding the button – it does need the full version of jQuery, rather than the slim version. jQuery’s slim version does not include animation functions (like hide).

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful and solved the probblem.

Comment: Would it be possible to hide the Button itself on click?